# Angularjs popup/modal content

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm in a AngularJS learning-by-doing stage, and this I can not figure out nor been able to find an answer for.

What I'm doing:

On ng-click I call a function in my controller, that $http-loads html-content (some divs and a form), that I "paste" to my ng-bind-html inside a div in my template.

That's working fine - but my problem is, that I'm not able to set values to the ng-models or {{someText}} in the loaded data. I get "undefined" on the elements inside the div (a modal-div with random content and therefore not a static part of my template).

I'm not using Bootstrap or anything similar.

What can I do to make the data a part of my scope - or to achieve what I want in another way (a modal div with random content)?

I can post some code, if that's any help to you. And when you answer please remember, I'm a totally newbie! :-)

-

**My directive:**

```
workApp.directive('modalDialog', function() {  
    return {  
        restrict: 'E',  
        scope: {  
            show: '='  
        },  
        transclude: true,  
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {  
            scope.dialogStyle = {};  
            if (attrs.boxWidth) scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.boxWidth;  
            if (attrs.boxHeight) scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.boxHeight;  
            scope.hideModal = function() {  
                scope.show = false;  
            };  
        },  
        templateUrl: 'app/tpl/modal.html'  
    };  
});
```

**States:**

```
.state('main', {  
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: tplMain  
})  

    // PROJECTS

    .state('main.projects', {  
        url: '/projects',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/projects/project-list.html',  
        controller: 'projectListCtrl'  
    })  

    .state('main.projectdetails', {  
        url: '/projects/:projectId/details',  
        templateUrl: 'app/views/projects/project-details.html',  
        controller: 'projectDetailsCtrl'  
    })
```

**The HTML (nested views):**

```
<!-- main -->
<div ui-view>   
    <!-- main.projects -->  
    <div ui-view>
        <a ng-click="newProject()">New project</a>
    </div>
</div>
<modal-dialog>{{message}}</modal-dialog>
```

**Controller:**

```
workApp.controller('projectListCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    $scope.newProject = function() {
        $scope.message = '<div>Some HTML here...</div>'; // Loaded from $http.get
        $scope.modalOpen = true;
    }
});
```

The first of my two problems is, that the modal doesn't show when i call newProject(). And I think it's because of the states / nested views (my modal-dialog is in another view)? If I copy the modal-dialog to my main.projects state it works.

The second is that {{message}} can't contain bindings, so I'm not able to bind fx. $scope.modal.title to {{modal.title}} in the HTML.

**UPDATE:**

I've found a working example that dynamically includes a html-file:

```
<div id="modal" ng-class="{ open: modal.data.visible }" ng-include="'app/views/' + modal.data.include"></div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.modal.data = {  
    include: 'projects/project-data.html',  
    visible: true,  
    title: 'New project',  
    subtitle: 'Enter project data',  
    projectName: 'My first project',  
    projectCompany: 'The Project Company'  
}
```

This seems to work very well - but is it bad practice versus a directive (that I still can not get to work).

Comment: you probably want a directive that can `$compile` it

Comment: Is your controller where your models are defined connected to the element in html where you are calling them? ex. <div ng-controller="yourController"></div>

Comment: I found a simpler version that binds a message in $scope to the modal, which I have revised in the code, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case, you are just wanting to pass data between the html and your modal.  Here is an [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q3eR4Snk0m2gMAr8Pft9) I found that you can review.  I've done similar things like this and a directive is the best solution I've found.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

 <head>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.3.2" data-require="bootstrap@*" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" data-semver="2.1.4" data-require="jquery@*"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" data-semver="3.3.2" data-require="bootstrap@*"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>

  <body ng-controller="indexCtrl">
  <h4 style="margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 20px;">Display a modal dialog with AngularJS</h4>
  <hr />
  <button ng-click="toggleModal()" class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' style="margin: 5px 0px 10px 10px;width: 150px;">Open Modal</button><br />

  <!-- Angular JS Directive Modal -->
  <modal-dialog box-width="400px" box-height="150px" show="modalShown">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <hr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- This is an important message -->
        {{message}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </modal-dialog>
</body>

</html>
```

**modalDialog.html**

```
<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>
  <div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>
  <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>
    <div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div>
    <div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
    angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('indexCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.modalShown = false;
  $scope.message= "This is an important message!"
  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
  };
});

angular.module('app').directive('modalDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    transclude: true, // Insert custom content inside the directive
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.boxWidth) {
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.boxWidth;
      }
      if (attrs.boxHeight) {
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.boxHeight;
      }
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'modalDialog.html'
  };
});
```

**CSS**

```
/* Styles go here */
.ng-modal-overlay {
  /* A dark translucent div that covers the whole screen */
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9999;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#808080;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.ng-modal-dialog {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px #595554;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index:10000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.ng-modal-dialog-content {
  padding:10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.ng-modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 120%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'arial', 'sans-serif';
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but as told in the original post I'm not using Bootstrap, so I'm facing some errors. Can this be done without it?

Comment: Yes, but I would opt to try to duplicate the code in plunker from the link I gave.  For a beginner in Angularjs custom directives aren't easy, but modifying a working example, albeit a more complex one will help you. Yours is not really a simple use case unless you have done it before..

Comment: But how can I change the "content" of the directive from the controller and make the bindings work? If my directive is a <modal></modal>, how can I from my controller decide what's in it? It's probably because I don't see the strength of the directive (or/and know how to use it), but why can't I just load some content through $http.get and append it with $compile to a div?

Comment: You can remove the bootstrap code, but it's just easier to work with, in my opinion.  See if this revised code illustrates things better without the noise of complexity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your last example! That's pretty much what I've been fiddling with for some time now. 2 things doesn't seem to work for me. 1: How do I make {{message}} work with bindings? Remember that I wan't to be able to change the content of the modal to almost everything (primary forms loaded with $http). And 2: I'm using ui-router with nested views/controllers. I'd like the modal to be in my main controller (first level) so that I can call the modal from wherever I wan't. But it seems the <modal-dialog/> must be in the same controller that's calling it?

Comment: You will have to show your code, I'm not good at guessing, so otherwise I won't be able to provide much more help.